# insert array into postgresql map prepared statement

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have this code :

```
require 'pg'
a = ["bla","foo","bar","test","wow"]

begin
con = PG.connect :dbname => 'base', :user => 'thatsme'

a.map do |e|
    con.prepare('statement1','INSERT INTO keywords (keyword, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)')
    con.exec_params('statement1', ["#{e}", '2017-01-01 07:29:33.096192', '2017-01-01 07:29:33.096192' ])
end
```

This causes an error, which is

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "statement1"
```

I don't get it. I'm missing something...

Comment: it seems like you should use double quotes with string interpolation:
`con.exec_params('statement1', ["#{e}", ...`

Comment: that's true too, thanks ! But that doesn't make the error go away. I still have `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "statement1"`

Comment: Things like `"#{e}"` are concerning and look like Cargo Cult Programming. If you want to be sure `e` is a string, use `e.to_s, though the driver often does this conversion automatically. Additionally, instead of banging against the low-level driver, try and use something with a bit of abstraction, like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net).

Comment: it still causes the same error, whether I do ` con.exec_params('statement1', [e.to_s, ... ` or `"#{e.so_s}", ....``

Comment: What I'm saying is drop the useless quotes. If `e` is a string then `"#{e}"` is just noise that distracts from what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`exec_params`](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-exec_params) method doesn't take a prepared statement name, that's not a supported argument.

You're probably intending to use the [`send_query_prepared`](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html?#method-i-send_query_prepared) method which does have that argument.

Here's a refactored version of your code:

```
a.each_with_index do |r, i|
  con.prepare("statement_#{i}","INSERT INTO keywords (keyword, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)")
  con.exec_prepared("statement_#{i}", [r, '2017-01-01 07:29:33.096192', '2017-01-01 07:29:33.096192' ])
end
```

You should use `each` instead of `map` if you're not concerned with the results, as `map` creates a temporary array of the rewritten entries. Additionally `each_with_index` avoids manually manipulating `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution (if this could help someone) :

```
con = PG.connect :dbname => 'base', :user => 'thatsme'
i = 1;

a.map do |r|
    con.prepare("statement_#{i}","INSERT INTO keywords (keyword, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)")
    con.exec_prepared("statement_#{i}", [r.to_s, '2017-01-01 07:29:33.096192', '2017-01-01 07:29:33.096192' ])
    i += 1
end
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this and other issues.

Comment: You should prepare your query only once, before the loop.